# FiOS signal bradcast

Tags: wireless-networking, compatibility, tv, video-streaming, fios

Can I connect the FiOS set top output coaxial cable to my MOCA wifi/router input so to broadcast the unscrambled signal to my Roku Boxes?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  The [FiOS STB](http://www22.verizon.com/residentialhelp/fiostv/receivers/user+guides/user+guides.htm) uses coax cable for TV channels; the [MoCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_over_Coax_Alliance) device uses the same cable to send data elsewhere in your house.

You need a device to convert the TV channels to streamable data, such as a [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com/) or [Vulkano](http://www.myvulkano.com/).  If you're using such a device, they let you stream TV from cable/FiOS (or your DVR) to your computer or mobile devices.  Some set-top boxes, such as the [Boxee Box](http://www.dlink.com/boxee/) or [SlingCatcher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VXD2S8), can receive streams from the Slingbox, but they aren't the main focus.